# Download part of the youtube video using python

Tags: python, youtube, download

Is it possible to download part of the youtube video?

Ex: out of 6 min length video, download only first 2 min or any time frame ?

Comment: [youtube-dl](http://rg3.github.io/youtube-dl/) and [gst-python](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/modules/gst-python.html) might help you.

Comment: Is it due to space requirements, such as, "I only have 1 megabyte of space"?

Comment: @user2565883 No, not about the space, about the time it takes full length video. In my example I said 6 min length but, I want to try the same for 120 min length video

Comment: @rogoro I will continue to look around, but I am not sure something like this exists. Two solutions I could see are:
1)download a video cut it to desired length automatically
2)kill the download when it is 'x'% done. For example, a 10 minute video that is 100mbs large, kill the download at 10mbs for a 1 minute video

The second idea is very ridiculous, and I wouldn't recommend. Just throwing it out there.

Comment: @user2565883 Appreciate it. Let me know if you find anything best.

Comment: Were you able to find a solution for this?

Comment: This is actually a feature request for the youtube-dl library. https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/issues/622
No progress on it but people have suggested ways to do it.

Comment: Add me to the list of people wanting this....

Answer (score 8):

This workaround might answer your question for now: https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/issues/622#issuecomment-320962680

1. Extract the url with `youtube-dl -g`
2. Use `sed` to prepends `-ss STARTTIME -i` to each line of output from `youtube-dl -g`
3. Set duration using the ffmpeg argument `-t`
4. Set the codec output to copy using `-c copy`

For example:

`ffmpeg $(youtube-dl -g 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NnW5EjwtE2U' | sed "s/.*/-ss 10 -i &/") -t 60 -c copy test3.mkv`

To get from 00:10 to 01:10 of this week's Last Week Tonight segment.

Comment: I think the above approach working fine, but takes too much time to complete even for small duration video also.